# How is 'yhat' (prediction) calculated in the fbprophet library?

Tags: python, time-series, prediction

I am using fbprophet for time-series predictions in Python and I am wondering how the `yhat` (prediction) column is calculated. I used the following code.

```
import quandl
import fbprophet

tesla = quandl.get('WIKI/TSLA')
tesla = tesla.reset_index()
tesla = tesla.rename(columns={'Date': 'ds', 'Adj. Close': 'y'})
tesla = tesla[['ds', 'y']]

prophet = fbprophet.Prophet()
prophet.fit(tesla)
future = prophet.make_future_dataframe(periods=365)
future = prophet.predict(future)
```

The `future` dataframe contains the following columns:

```
['ds', 'trend', 'trend_lower', 'trend_upper', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper', 
'seasonal', 'seasonal_lower', 'seasonal_upper', 'seasonalities', 
'seasonalities_lower', 'seasonalities_upper', 'weekly', 'weekly_lower', 
'weekly_upper', 'yearly', 'yearly_lower', 'yearly_upper', 'yhat']
```

I understand `yhat` is the prediction, but is it a combination of `trend, seasonal, seasonalities, weekly, yearly` or something else?

I have tried combining the `trend, seasonal, seasonalities, weekly, yearly` columns to see if they equal the `yhat` column, but they do not:

```
future['combination'] = future['trend'] + future['seasonal'] + future['weekly'] + future['yearly'] + future['seasonalities']

print(future[['combination', 'yhat']].head())

   combination       yhat
0    57.071956  27.681139
1    55.840545  27.337270
2    53.741200  26.704090
3    51.874192  26.148355
4    47.827763  25.065950
```

I have been unable to find an answer in the documentation, but apologize if I have simply missed it.

Answer (score 2):

I am a beginner of `fbprophet` but would like to share my guess.
Even though I'm not sure it is correct, The following equation probably holds true in the default setting of prophet.

```
yhat = trend + seasonal
```

Hopefully, my answer will help you!

Comment: Thanks. Was this in the documentation?

Comment: @caseWestern From their [Homepage](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/) you can read the [article](https://peerj.com/preprints/3190/)

Comment: @user32185. I think you are right. I looked through the [github](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/master/python/fbprophet/forecaster.py) source code, and found `df2['yhat'] = df2['trend'] + df2['seasonal']` under the predict method for the Prophet object.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have changed now. Looking at Github code, `yhat` is calculated as below

```
yhat = (trend * (1 + multiplicative_terms) + additive_terms
```

A link to this calculation in the `fbprophet` source code is found

- [here](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/cd8a24eddd6bebb9888f2e0ae2388f209047b02d/python/prophet/forecaster.py#L1222-L1225) for Python
- [here](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/cd8a24eddd6bebb9888f2e0ae2388f209047b02d/R/R/prophet.R#L1354) for `R`